# Is it possible to send another ip address in a HTTP(S) request?

Tags: web-services, ip

There is a web service (in an Intranet environment) what checks the client IP and if it is not a valid IP then refuses the request. Is there any opportunity to cheat at this web service with the IP?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is prefectly possible to send IP packets with fake IP addresses. However, you won't get a reply because the reply will be directed at the fake IP address. This means that you can't establish TCP connections (upon which HTTP(S) depends) because they require two-way IP traffic.